# Open a ".exe" with a Button using a file path from a TextBox

Tags: vb.net, process.start

I have a TextBox called TextBox1, which is filled by a Button that gets a file path using OpenFileDialog. I want a button (Button3) to start several processes one after another with an interval of 2 hours then close it and open the next one.

In total I have 4 different TextBoxes (TextBox1, TextBox2, TextBox3 and TextBox4) and 4 different file paths that I want to open with the same button with the interval I mentioned before.

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        OpenFileDialog1.Title = "Please Select a File"
        OpenFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "C:temp"
        OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
    End Sub

    Private Sub OpenFileDialog1_FileOk(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles OpenFileDialog1.FileOk
        Dim strm As System.IO.Stream
        strm = OpenFileDialog1.OpenFile()
        TextBox1.Text = OpenFileDialog1.FileName.ToString()
        If Not (strm Is Nothing) Then

            'insert code to read the file data

            strm.Close()
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        OpenFileDialog2.Title = "Please Select a File"
        OpenFileDialog2.InitialDirectory = "C:temp"
        OpenFileDialog2.ShowDialog()
    End Sub

    Private Sub OpenFileDialog2_FileOk(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles OpenFileDialog2.FileOk
        Dim strm As System.IO.Stream
        strm = OpenFileDialog2.OpenFile()
        TextBox3.Text = OpenFileDialog2.FileName.ToString()
        If Not (strm Is Nothing) Then

            'insert code to read the file data

            strm.Close()
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBox3_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox3.TextChanged
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Are you really using VBA.?

Comment: I'm using studio, and open a Visual Basic Aplication for windows project.

Comment: Then you're using VB.NET, which is a different language from VBA.   You're more likely to get help if you fix your tags.

Comment: Indeed, [VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/vba/info) specifically refers to the programming language that interfaces with MS Office products (Word, Excel, PowerPoint, Access).

Comment: Please show us the code that you already have.

Comment: You've pasted in a bunch of code, but you've failed to explain what problem you're having with that code and you have not asked a question. What **specific problem** are you asking us to help you solve?

Comment: You would usually go with Process.Start on the onclick button sub, but I don't know how to extract info (file path) from TextBox1 to open it with button1, how do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To launch a new process use:

```
dim myProcess = Process.start(filename)
```

You dont' need the code that does the following:

```
    Dim strm As System.IO.Stream
    strm = OpenFileDialog2.OpenFile()
    If Not (strm Is Nothing) Then
        strm.Close()
    End If
```

This is opening the exe file as if it were trying to read the data from it.

Instead just use

```
   dim process = Process.Start(OpenFileDialogX.Filename)
```

Note: your initial directory seems to be c:temp not c:\temp as it probably should be